# how to display a name from database using jade page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

```
    **app.js file**

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbConnect
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", function(err, db){
    dbConnect = db;
});
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    dbConnect.collection("users").find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {

            app.render("index", {docs: docs});
        }
    });
});



    **index.jade file**

    ul
      each name in docs
        li= name


    The result shows only blank screen. I'm a beginner in node js. Here I want to display a collection of name from database to index.jade.
```

aaaaaa The result shows only blank screen. I'm a beginner in node js. Here I want to display a collection of name from database to index.jade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .jade template, You are iterating over *docs* object.

```
ul
    each name in docs
        li= name.prop1
        li= name.prop2
        li= name.prop3
```

You should use property names, not the object(name) of type(docs).

Also refer [this link](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) for more info.